# Django 1.11 Allauth google token authetication and token validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have Django rest framework (DRF) setup with allauth to allow google authentication as external authentication I am not using any built in authentication like register user and so on.
In my DRF I do have protected resource which I intend to use to protect them using auth_token received for that respective user. I can see after hitting google Oauth URL I am able to  login and I can see Django Admin backend that following tables like 
“SocialAccounts” I can see user there and in “Social Application Token” table I can see user and respective authe_token with refresh token along with expiry timing.

My use cases are as following

- In my Django views I want to use that auth_token for that user to
  create session
- Upon expiry of auth_token it should be auto
  refresh so that client  should not every time re authenticate them
  self.
- Is it possible to use Auth_token in as JWT token  pass along
  with header for protected resources in DRF so that it will  not be
  accessed unwanted users.

If someone can guide me to any documentation or use case scenario would be great help.

### settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'feufm)u(pvsvb%&_%%*)p_bpa+sv8zt$#_-do5q3(vou-j*d#p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #Django Project Apps
    'persons',
    'earningtype',
    'expensetype',
    'investmtype',
    'Earnings',
    'Expenses',
    'Shares',
    'Investment',
    #Django Third party
    'rest_framework',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    #'social_django',


]

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            ]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoE2ISAapi.urls'
SITE_ID = 1

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoE2ISAapi.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': 'C:\\my.cnf',
        },
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#File upload setting are here
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upd_files')
MEDIA_PATH = '/media'

from DjangoE2ISAapi.restconf.main import *
```

### urls.py

```
"""DjangoE2ISAapi URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token,refresh_jwt_token,verify_jwt_token
from .restconf import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^',include('persons.api.urls'),name='home'),
    url(r'^api/persons/',include('persons.api.urls'),name='HOME'),
    url(r'^api/eartypes/',include('earningtype.api.urls')),
    url(r'^api/exptypes/',include('expensetype.api.urls')),
    url(r'^api/invtypes/',include('investmtype.api.urls')),
    url(r'^api/auth/jwt/',obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/auth/jwt/refresh',refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/auth/jwt/verify',verify_jwt_token),
    url(r'^new',views.index),
    url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

**New Update**
After changing my setting.py file with following things i can create session and authenticate my self with google oauth2.

settings.py

```
    """
    Django settings for DjangoE2ISAapi project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.15.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'feufm)u(pvsvb%&_%%*)p_bpa+sv8zt$#_-do5q3(vou-j*d#p'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        #Django Project Apps
        'persons',
        'earningtype',
        'expensetype',
        'investmtype',
        'Earnings',
        'Expenses',
        'Shares',
        'Investment',
        'accounts',
        #Django Third party
        'rest_framework',
        'allauth',
        'allauth.account',
        'allauth.socialaccount',
        'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
        #'social_django',


    ]

    SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
        'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
        'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
        'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
        'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details'
    )

    ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
    SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/api/persons"

    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
        'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
        'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
                ]


    ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoE2ISAapi.urls'
    SITE_ID = 1

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
            ,
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoE2ISAapi.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'read_default_file': 'C:\\my.cnf',
            },
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    #File upload setting are here
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upd_files')
    MEDIA_PATH = '/media'
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
                'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
                'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
                # 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
                #'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
#

    from DjangoE2ISAapi.restconf.main import *
```

Now how would i use google given auth_token as authorization header in HTTP request(GET,POST,PUT) for protected api resource.

I am skeptical that session which django all auth create for google oauth2 can be used in mobile app for Java script front end.
Any one used this scenario kindly comment it.

for Django-allauth request to use google auth-token as Authorization header for user are still in progress no dates are given for the same.
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1983

Comment: Did you slove???

Comment: its complicated to impersonate Django All auth in react SPA front end
https://github.com/niravhjoshi/DjangoE2ISAapi